# Search2 - Ajax results with no search

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using ajax to pull in data from a php file (which returns json).

I'm wondering, can you have results pulled from Ajax and loads on click without having to search? so essentially you click the field, it drops down with all the elements from Ajax. Couldn't find in the documentation.

Code:

```
 jQuery('.producttypesajax').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: {
    id: '',
      text: 'Search by Product Type'
    },
ajax: {
  url: base + '/appProductTypeSearch.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250,
  data: function( params ) {
    return {
      q: params.term // search term
    };
  },
  processResults: function( data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };
  },
  cache: true
},
minimumInputLength: 1
  });

  jQuery('.producttypesajax').on('select2:select', function (e) {
var data = e.params.data;
 });
```

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: I actually just got here looking for the same thing.  I have a select2 and I want to change the options list based off the value from somewhere else on the page.  Did you figure anything out for this?  As a last resort I guess the options could be cleared and loaded in on change, but I haven't looked into that either.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [there's no native solution](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3828) for this, but I managed to do it somehow.

Since Select2 accepts Arrays as a data source, you can make an Ajax request returning your Json object and use it as an "Array".

Sample code:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (jsonObject){
        $('#mySelect').select2({ data: jsonObject });
     }
});
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps.